# Prove that if lines $FP$ and $GQ$ intersect at $M$, then $\angle MAC = 90^\circ$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> In convex cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$, we know that lines $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $E$, lines $AB$ and $CD$ intersect at $F$, and lines $BC$ and $DA$ intersect at $G$. Suppose that the circumcircle of $\triangle ABE$ intersects line $CB$ at $B$ and $P$, and the circumcircle of $\triangle ADE$ intersects line $CD$ at $D$ and $Q$, where $C,B,P,G$ and $C,Q,D,F$ are collinear in that order. Prove that if lines $FP$ and $GQ$ intersect at $M$, then $\angle MAC = 90^\circ$.

**My Progress**:

[image]

**Claim** : $PBQD$ is cyclic

**Proof**: Note that $CQ\cdot CD=CE\cdot CA=CB\cdot CP \implies PQDB$ is cyclic.

**Claim**: $APQC$ is cyclic

**Proof** : angle chase! Note that for this to be true , it is enough to show that $\angle AEB=\angle AQC$ or it is enough to show that $\angle AEB=\angle AQC $ or it is enough to show that $\angle AED=\angle AQD$ which is true since $AEDQ$ is cyclic.

**Claim**: $E\in PQ$

**Proof**: So enough to show that $\angle AEQ+\angle AEP=180 $

or enough to show that $180- \angle ADC + \angle AEP=180 $

or enough to show that $\angle ADC= \angle ABC$ , which is true since $ABCD$ is cyclic.

after that I am stuck.

I observed that $FG , AM, PQ$ concur but was not able to prove. Can someone give hints?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: As a beginner in Olympiad math just seeing 5+ circles in one diagram makes me anxious

Comment: @l1mbo lol, even I was like you , but now,  the more the circles in the diagram , more I like the problem :)

Comment: Have you guys learned calculus, linear algebra and simillar topics?

Comment: @1b3b no , not in school atleast and I know only basic calculus..

Comment: @1b3b I have not learned linear algebra but do know some calculus (although not taught in school); moreover I am curious how we can use calculus in a purely geometric question which doesn't even involve any areas

Comment: @l1mbo , I guess he was asking this question in general , not related with this question ..

Comment: @Shubhangi, yes. I am interested in what math competitors learn in other countries. For example, I qualified for the state (Croatia) competition this year, but I learned Calculus 1 and basics of Calculus 2 on my own this summer (when I said learned I meant on understanding all rules, theorems, etc.). Also a lot of other topics are not even mentioned before college. But I think olympiad approach is better because it develops problem solving skills which is ground for math research

Comment: Hi shubhangi, this might not be the best place to ask, but I was curious- are you not going to prepare for JEE? Or are you a maybe aiming to clear KVPY and get into IISc? Asking because I'm also a student of class XI

Comment: well , I want to clear CMI/ ISI  entrance exam . :) What about you ?

Comment: @Shubhangi first thanks, after seeing you I got in mood to do some extra math beyond the regular studies and gained some rep here too! And I hope to see you in ISI the year after (if I make it ;) I am also 11th grader

Comment: @Arjun that's so sweet :) .

Comment: I see, that's great. I am hoping to get into IISc through KVPY, if not then IISER and pursue a degree in Physics P.S.You forgot to tag me, so I never saw your message until now :(

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from where you finished...

So, we have $PBDQ$ cyclic and $E\in PQ$. Now focus on quadrilateral $PBDQ$. From definition $A$ is the Miquel Point of the quadrilateral $PBDQ$. Now let $X:=PD\cap BQ$ and thus, by Miquel point properties, we get that $A$ is projection of $X$ on $CE$. Thus, its enough to show that $M,A,X$ are collinear but this is trivial. Just apply Pappus Theorem on $\{PGB,QFD\}$  completing the proof. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you so much ! I saw your profile , OMG , congrats for INMO, sharygin  and IGO . You are so Pro !!! Can you give me some Geo and NT  advice , please ? Plus Can I pm you in AOPS if I get any doubt ?

Comment: @Shubhangi Thanks but I'm a noob! My AoPS id is Jupiter_is_BIG what's yours?

Comment: mine is Jelena_ivanchic :) . But looks like due to some reasons I can't PM you .. Anyways Thanks for your solution .

Comment: @Shubhangi GOD, you won't believe but I got two major hints for that...
1) You put a space in front and after every comma or question mark or exclamation mark
2) You are the only AoPSer who know bout SOR (expect Muler)